# Linq : Where + keeping order

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq

I currently have a list of Ids, lets say

```
List<int> ids = {3, 1, 2}
```

I whish to call IQueryable for all the items from the list, but keeping the ids order.
For now I do this:

```
var result = query.Where(x => ids.Contains(w.Id)).ToList();
```

The problem is that I lost the order.

One solution is to add this:

```
.OrderBy(i => ids.IndexOf(i));
```

But it is an additional ORDER clause in SQL, not sure about performance !

Is there a more efficient way ?

Comment: The order of the elements isn´t guaranteed in any way, so you shouldn´t rely on `Where` to maintain any specific order. Instead you should use some order by with some specific attribute

Answer (score 1):

The `Where` clause in your query will eventually get translated to something like (in standard SQL):

```
WHERE w.Id IN (3, 1, 2)
```

There is no way in standard SQL to specify that the order of the output should match the order of the matching items in the `IN` clause. For that, you would need to do a fairly complex SQL statement (e.g. `ORDER BY CASE WHEN Id = 3 THEN 1 WHEN Id = 1 THEN 2 ...`), which may be impossible to represent in Linq. Some alternatives are:

- Query for each ID individually, concatenating the results
- Querying everything and ordering in-memory (the method you suggest is perfectly fine)

The only way to know which is better performance-wise is to try them both and measure the results.